# Check if local user is enabled or disabled

Tags: windows, powershell

I need a seemingly simple `if` code that would check if a local user is enabled or disabled.

After check has been made I need to disable a user which is simple (`Disable-LocalUser -Name "User"`), however I cannot work out a part that would first check if a user is in enabled state.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have the name of the user in `$user`

```
if ((Get-LocalUser -Name $user).Enabled)
{
    <#disable code here#>
}
```

This should work.

EDIT Detailed:

```
$User = "blahblah"
try
{
    $Result = (Get-LocalUser -Name $user -ErrorAction Stop).Enabled
    try
    {
        if ($Result)
        {
            "disable code here"
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        $_.Exception.Message #in case disable fails
    }
}
catch
{
    $_.Exception.Message #if user doesnt exist
}
```

Comment: Thank you thats perfect. One more thing a little bit unrelated but how would you do the same IF statement that checks if a certain local user account exists.

Comment: if the user doesn't exist, the command `(Get-LocalUser -Name $user).Enabled` will throw an exception. You can enclose it in `try-catch` to handle it. I will update.

Answer (score 0):

You could check `Enabled` state with a `Where-Object` and directly pipe to `Disable-LocalUser` provided the script runs elevated.

```
PoSh> Get-LocalUser -Name TestUser | Where-Object Enabled

Name     Enabled Description
----     ------- -----------
TestUser True    UserTest


PoSh> Get-LocalUser -Name TestUser | Where-Object Enabled | Disable-LocalUser
PoSh> Get-LocalUser -Name TestUser

Name     Enabled Description
----     ------- -----------
TestUser False   UserTest
```